# I need fscanf advice

Tags: c, scanf

I want to `fprintf()` 3 strings to a file, all on the same line.

The first two cannot contain spaces while the 3rd may. I.E. `word word rest of line`

Can some one tell me how to `fscanf()` that into 3 variables?

I don't mind putting some delimiters if it makes it easier. E.G. `[word] [word] [rest of line]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without delimiters, too:

```
char s1[32], s2[32], s3[256];

if(sscanf(line, "%31s %31s %255[^\n]", S1, S2, S3) == 3)
 /* ... */
```

This should work, as long as the input `line` actually does end with a newline.

Of course, you should adjust the string sizes to fit. Also you can get trickery with the preprocessor to avoid repeating the sizes, but doing so makes it more complicated so I avoided that for this example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scanf` to scan two words, then use `fgets` to get the rest of the line.

```
FILE *f = stdin; // or use fopen to open a saved file

// use buffers large enough for your needs
char word1[20];
char word2[20];
char restOfLine[100];

// make sure fscanf returns 2 (indicating 2 items scanned successfully)
fscanf(f, "%20s %20s", word1, word2); 

// make sure fgets returns &restOfLine[0]
fgets(restOfLine, sizeof restOfLine, f);
```

Note that if `fgets` encounters a `'\n'` character, it is put into the buffer as well, so if you don't want it, you'll have to strip it out manually. If `fscanf` returns something other than 2, or `fgets` returns `NULL`, then there was a problem reading your input.